# Configure Wii Classic controller on DOSBox

Tags: retropie

NOTE: This is a duplicate from stack overflow. As I haven't got any responses there, I am reasking it here in hopes that because this is a RasPi-specific forum I'll get an answer.

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with retropie installed. I use cwiid to pair a wii remote with classic controller attached, to my Pi. I used to be able to use the analog sticks in games like Rebel Assault in DOSBox. Now whenever I boot up or use my attachwii.sh script to connect the wii remote, I get the following message:`Warning: duplicate absolute axis assignment`. I can ctl-c out of the script and thee wii remote pairs fine. I can use the d-pad in Emulationstation but in dosbox, the analog sticks can't be used, even trying to map them doesn't work.  Currently, it seems that the joystick controls are bound to the d-pad, and the mapper does not recognize the analog stick. Additionally, when I log in via ssh my console is flooded with a `Socket connect error (control channel)` error (this is actually a known issue, but I can't seem to carry out the fix.)

mywminput:

```
Classic.Dpad.X = ABS_X
Classic.Dpad.Y = ABS_Y
Classic.LStick.X = ABS_HAT0X
Classic.LStick.Y = ABS_HAT0Y
Classic.RStick.X = ABS_HAT1X
Classic.RStick.Y = ABS_HAT1Y
Classic.A = BTN_A
Classic.B = BTN_B
Classic.X = BTN_X
Classic.Y = BTN_Y
Classic.Minus = BTN_SELECT
Classic.Plus  = BTN_START
Classic.Home  = BTN_MODE
Classic.L  = BTN_TL
Classic.R  = BTN_TR
Classic.ZL = BTN_TL2
Classic.ZR = BTN_TR2
Wiimote.A       = BTN_A
Wiimote.B       = BTN_B
Wiimote.Dpad.X      = -ABS_Y
Wiimote.Dpad.Y      = ABS_X
Wiimote.Minus   = BTN_SELECT
Wiimote.Plus    = BTN_START
Wiimote.Home    = BTN_MODE
Wiimote.1       = BTN_X
Wiimote.2       = BTN_Y
Plugin.led.Led1 = 1
```

attachwii.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
hcitool dev | grep hci >/dev/null
if test $? -eq 0 ; then
   sudo wminput -d -c  /home/pi/mywminput 2C:10:C1:1B:88:1D 
else
    echo "Blue-tooth adapter not present!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Please remember not to cross post questions across SE sites, as it is frowned upon on SE. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu. It is better to ask for your question to be migrated. However, I understand why you did, and it is good that you finally have an answer. BTW, I have flagged your previous question on SO for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember how I got to this, but I solved the flood issue by adding `-q` before the path to `mywminput` and then adding `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` at the end as you can see.

```
wminput -d -q -c  /home/pi/mywminput 2C:10:C1:1B:88:1D > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Solved the duplicate absolute axis assignment problem, however dosbox still does not recognize the classic controller's analog sticks. I have deleted the SO version of this question.