# Using Wii Classic controller with I2C/GPIO on RPi 2

Tags: pi-2, retropie

I'm planning on creating a Retropie system to install into my car for road trips.

The controller I'd like to use is a Black Wii Classic Controller.

Had I seen [Configure Wii Classic controller on DOSBox](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/configure-wii-classic-controller-on-dosbox) earlier I would have not cut the cord on the controller so hastily, but things being the way they are this is not the case. I do not want to solder the piece I cut off back on either. But I still think this is for the best as there definitely would be lag going through Bluetooth compared to a wired connection.

I don't believe anyone has provided a guide for the Wii Classic Controller connected to the RP2, but I'd imagine it would be utilizing the I2C/GPIO connectors (I've seen a Nunchuk connected that way). Of course, my next step after getting connected would be to throw a script together but first things first.

Here are some photos of the Controller cable. I need to figure out which of the smaller cables will need to be connected.

[image: Controller cable #1]

[image: Controller cable #2]

Which of the above cables will need to be utilized? I'm not sure what the thin (copper?) wires surrounding the coloured cables are for, or the central copper wire. My guess is it's a ground connection and the thin wires are protection.

I'll probably have to open up the controller to see what the Red, White, Yellow, and Green cable control. I don't have the controller in front of me ATM but I don't recall if it has screws on the body so I'll have to try to pry it open carefully.

If anyone can give me a hand in identifying these cables that would be a big help.

Comment: Retro pie forum is your friend for questions about retro pie. Here is a link:
https://retropie.org.uk/forum/

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that the wire colors could be non-standard, my guess would be that red=3.3v, white=ground, green=SDA, yellow=SCL -- at least that's how I have an extension cable that hooks into the original male end of that cable wired.